# Overriding the sort order of the built-in search

Tags: search-results

Using MOSS 2007. Is it possible to change sort order for the Search Center to be based on a field other than "modified date" or "relevance"? I'd like to sort by Created (descending). Doing this programmatically IS an option. Would someone tell me how/if I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible OOTB. You can write your own custom code using SharePoint search APIs in which you can use any of the managed property for ordering the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the XSLT that is used by sharepoint search to achieve sorting column. for help u might want to go through this link...
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cZ-Ww9jbDNQJ:social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepointserverknowledgenetwork/thread/90845216-da59-494d-9c3c-9af5d529803d&hl=en&gl=in&prmd=imvns&strip=1